# Oracle Silent Install Failing in Chef

Tags: linux, bash, oracle, chef-infra, rhel

I'm trying to install Oracle on a RHEL VM in Chef. When I directly log into the VM as the install user ("oracle1") and run the silent install command:

```
./runInstaller -ignorePrereq -waitforcompletion -silent -responseFile /u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/dbhome_1/install/response/db_install.rsp
```

the installation is successful.

I want to automate this installation by adding it to my existing Chef recipes, which I am currently attempting using the following block:

```
execute 'install oracle' do
  command './runInstaller -ignorePrereq -waitforcompletion -silent -responseFile /u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/dbhome_1/install/response/db_install.rsp'
  cwd '/u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/dbhome_1'
  user 'oracle1'
  group 'oinstall'
  #not_if { ::File.exist?("/u01/app/oracle/product/completed.txt") }
end
```

However, this block fails and results in the following error:

```
[FATAL] [INS-32042] The Installer has detected that the user (oracle1) is not a member of the central inventory group: oinstall
ACTION: Make sure that the user (oracle1) is member of the central inventory group (oinstall)
```

But, previously in the recipe, I run the block:

```
execute 'luseradd' do
  command 'sudo luseradd -g oinstall -d /home/oracle1 -s /bin/bash oracle1'
  not_if { Dir.exist?("/home/oracle1") }
end
```

which (as far as I am aware) contradicts the error message I get. Also, when I check the groups that oracle1 is part of, oinstall is listed as one of them.

Any help/pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: A couple things to check: try `chown -R oracle:oinstall /u01/app/oracle` to make sure permissions are correct, and look in the response file to see what the `oracle.install.db.*` groups are being set to.

Comment: I have checked both of these and both look correct to me. The ownership command is already being ran and I'm fairly sure all the groups in the rsp are correct

Comment: Groups listed in the rsp:
1. oracle.install.db.OSDBA_GROUP=dba
2. oracle.install.db.OSOPER_GROUP=osoper
3. oracle.install.db.OSBACKUPDBA_GROUP=backupdba
4. oracle.install.db.OSDGDBA_GROUP=dgdba
5. oracle.install.db.OSKMDBA_GROUP=kmdba
6. oracle.install.db.OSRACDBA_GROUP=racdba

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the execute block like this:

```
execute 'install oracle' do 
 command 'sudo -Eu oracle1 ./runInstaller -ignorePrereq -waitforcompletion -silent -responseFile /u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/dbhome_1/install/response/db_install.rsp'    
 cwd '/u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/dbhome_1'
 #not_if { ::File.exist?("/u01/app/oracle/product/completed.txt") }  
end
```

Additionally you may need to modify your user oracle1 so it can execute commands without passing root password.